# Any way to store extra information for the printing phase in .oxps (ECMA-388)?

Tags: printing, standards, xps

Reminder: XPS or OXPS is a document format for printing purpose. It is now normalized and a standard: ECMA-388. At its beginning, it was designed to be a viable alternative to PDF (which it is, I guess).

I don't see in its documentation any "official" way to store extra-informations destined to be used during the printing phase or post-processing phase (said finish phase). Like the use of a cutter, staples or any more technical commands for the printer.

How would you do that?

- the PrintTickets can carry some of it (if it was designed for it)
- but, everything else can just be part of extra Resources files, unreferenced...

I'm opened to critics.